# Wordpress: Access to post from wp_headers

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I'm trying to set a new http Header for my wordpress installation but I'm not able to work with $post object inside my new wp_headers filter function. I want to send different headers for diferent post types and use Go(lang) for caching stuff (home project).

```
    function add_new_header($headers) { 
        $headers['PostId'] = get_the_ID();
        return $headers;
    }

    add_filter('wp_headers', 'add_new_header');
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems Like I can't access to Post / get_queried_object_id() in the hook as it's not started.

So, referencing post attributes, you have to do in the "template_redirect" hook. As in that moment the Post exists...

```
    add_action('template_redirect', 'add_new_header');
    function add_new_header($headers) { 
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        if( $post_id ) {
            header("PostId: " .  $post_id) ;
        }
    }
```

Hope helps to someone.. someday...